# getting distinct sorted date values ignoring datetime

Tags: xslt-1.0, xls

I have the following xml / xsl:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="./test.xsl"?>

<a>
  <b>
    <c >
      <no>1</no>
      <d>
        <e>
          <f>20060603190000</f>
        </e>
      </d>
    </c>
    <c >
      <no>1</no>
      <d>
        <e>
          <f>20060603190000</f>
        </e>
      </d>
    </c>
    <c>
      <no>2</no>
      <d>
        <e>
          <f>20060603190000</f>
        </e>
      </d>
    </c>
    <c >
      <no>1</no>
      <d>
        <e>
          <f>20060819200000</f>
        </e>
        <e>
          <f>20060902200000</f>
        </e>
      </d>
    </c>
    <c >
      <no>1</no>
      <d>
        <e>
          <f>20070819200000</f>
        </e>
        <e>
          <f>20070819200003</f>
        </e>
        <e>
          <f>20070819200001</f>
        </e>
        <e>
          <f>20060903100000</f>
        </e>
      </d>
    </c>
    <c >
      <no>1</no>
      <d>
        <e>
          <f>20060819200000</f>
        </e>
        <e>
          <f>20060902200000</f>
        </e>
      </d>
    </c>
  </b>
</a>


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-15"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="1.0" >
  <xsl:output method="text" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:template match="/">

  <table>
    <tr>
    <xsl:for-each select="a/b/c[no=1]/d/e/f[not(.=preceding::*)]" ><xsl:sort select="." data-type="number"/>&#160;
      <td><xsl:value-of select="."/></td>
    </xsl:for-each>
    </tr>
  </table>

  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

when applied, the result looks like this:

20060603190000 
20060819200000 
20060902200000 
20060903100000 
20070819200000 
20070819200001 
20070819200003

which is partly correct, since:

- i want to display distinct values of f (which works)
- i want to sort the values of f (which works too)

but:

i want to display values that are distinct for the first 8 digits only (year, month, day), so that the result would be:

20060603190000 
20060819200000 
20060902200000 
20060903100000 
20070819200000

ie values with the same date but different time are seen as equal.

I have tried to use substring(values, 8) in different places, but i can't get it to work that way nor using key/generate-id.
Can anyone please give me advise on that?

edited:

i have solved the problem on my own.

the following template create a string containing all dates sorted by time and truncated to the first 8 digits (the date withaout the time):

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:variable name="text">
    <xsl:for-each select="a/b/c[no=1]/d/e/f[not(.=preceding::*)]" ><xsl:sort select="." data-type="number"/>
      <xsl:value-of select="substring(.,0,9)"/>-</xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:variable>

  text:<xsl:value-of select="$text"/>
  <xsl:call-template name="filter"><xsl:with-param name="text"><xsl:value-of select="$text"/></xsl:with-param><xsl:with-param name="previousElement"/></xsl:call-template >
</xsl:template>
```

output example: 20060603-20060819-20060902-20060902-20060902-20060903-20070819-20070819-20070819-20110902-20110902-

then a second template is called which outputs the distinct values by recursivly calling itself:

```
<xsl:template name="filter">
  <xsl:param name="text"/>
  <xsl:param name="previousElement"/>

  <xsl:variable name="firstElement"><xsl:value-of select="substring-before($text, '-')"/></xsl:variable>
  <xsl:variable name="rest"><xsl:value-of select="substring-after($text, '-')"/></xsl:variable>

<!--    firstElement:<xsl:value-of select="$firstElement"/>
  previousElement:<xsl:value-of select="$previousElement"/>
  rest:<xsl:value-of select="$rest"/>
-->
  <xsl:if test="string-length($firstElement) > 0">
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="$firstElement = $previousElement">
        <xsl:call-template name="filter"><xsl:with-param name="text"><xsl:value-of select="$rest"/></xsl:with-param><xsl:with-param name="previousElement"><xsl:value-of select="$firstElement"/></xsl:with-param></xsl:call-template >
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        output:<xsl:value-of select="$firstElement"/>
        <xsl:call-template name="filter"><xsl:with-param name="text"><xsl:value-of select="$rest"/></xsl:with-param><xsl:with-param name="previousElement"><xsl:value-of select="$firstElement"/></xsl:with-param></xsl:call-template >
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Could you include your code attempts that you have written so far?

Comment: What you should do now is to use your code and answer your own question and accept it. This way the question will be marked as closed and help others searching th site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i answered my question myself as seen above. according to the advice of Marcus Rickert i will answer it this way and accept it to make it closable and maybe helpful for others.